# Basic firebase! (Using android studio)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so I am trying to create a very simple android app that connects to firebase. i have created a firebase account and have seen sample code, etc. I am still struggling with getting to literally just write to firebase. I am very desperate and if someone could literally just post the code on how to click a button on adnroid studio (NO textbox please! this is a common feature and one I do not need!), that would upload "hello world!" to firebase I think I can figure out how to add the other necessary features to my app.I know it sounds simple but a lot of tutorials seem to be outdated and if someone could just help me with this I would be so appreciative! also please DO NOT include a sign in or any authentication features. I have most of my app done and really need this! thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is a site where we strive to help with programming problems. This typically requires some example code and the error message you encounter. As your question is lacking either, please add them. In case you want to learn more about how to ask a good question, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: At this point my code is so messy this wouldn't help. Also there is no error message, I believe I am doing everything right, but it is not uploading. here are the tutorials I have looked at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yt75ZIGdJ4Y and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efEQBNuCCTw

Comment: Please read [ask] pages to understand which questions are appropriate at [so]. In it's current condition your question does not meet these criteria. It would help a lot if you can create a [mcve] of your connection/update issue. Understand asking for working code is not in the spirit of this site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you have configured the Firebase SDK correctly, tried using the snippet in the the Firebase docs, and still cannot write to the database, it is likely that you haven't configured your rules to allow unauthenticated database writes. In the Firebase dashboard, change your rules to the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```